# How to remove Cell in xlsx file using apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to remove cell content in xlsx file. My code:

```
static void RemoveCell(XSSFSheet mySheet) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
int rownum = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
for (int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
    Row currentRow = mySheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = currentRow.getCell(0);
    if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    }
}
```

It can remove cell content but can't remove cell. Thank!

Comment: What exactly is your goal? If you imagine a spreadsheet grid, what purpose does it have to "remove a cell"? If you try to remove cell B3 from Excel, for example, you cannot, you can only change the value. What is your overall goal?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove cell content not cell, you can set the value to null. Refer the below code

```
currentRow.getCell(0).setCellValue(null);
```

Comment: i want to remove cell

Comment: @KiênHoàngTrung, You mentioned as "I want to remove cell content in xlsx file" in your question..so i thought removing content.. If you want to remove cell, then invoke removeCell(cell) method by passing cell you want to remove